# GCP - User ... does not have permission to access projects instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, service-accounts, google-iam

I was using `gcloud` with a service account to try to figure out why my API Gateway endpoint didn't work when I ran into another problem. First I ran this `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/credential/fils/PROJECTNAME-hash.json`. Then I ran `gcloud services list --available` and I got this in my terminal:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.services.list) User [<SERVICE ACCOUNT NAME>@<MY PROJECT NAME>.iam.gserviceaccount.com] does not have permission to access projects instance [<MY PROJECT NAME>] (or it may not exist): Permission denied to list services for consumer container [projects/<MY PROJECT ID>]
Help Token: <WHAT LOOKS LIKE AN API KEY>
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure
  violations:
  - subject: ?error_code=110002&service=cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com&permission=serviceusage.services.list&resource=projects/<MY PROJECT NAME>
    type: googleapis.com
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo
  domain: serviceusage.googleapis.com
  metadata:
    permission: serviceusage.services.list
    resource: projects/<MY PROJECT NAME>
    service: cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com
  reason: AUTH_PERMISSION_DENIED
```

I believe I have the correct permissions enabled in my service account:
[image]

So why am I getting this error and how do I get `gcloud services list --available` to work with the selected service account?

Comment: Are you setting expected project context for your cli gcp client?

Comment: I'm not sure. How would I check for this? The command I'm doing is just a raw bash terminal gcloud terminal command: `gcloud services list --available`

Comment: You could exclude this(is the root cause) by trying the services list from cloud shell actually: https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?cloudshell=true . For project context, refers to docs: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set

Comment: Oh interesting. The cloudshell DID work. First it made me click authorize on a popup that said  "Authorize Cloud Shell Cloud Shell needs permission to use your credentials for the cloud command. Click Authorize to grant permission to this and future calls." Then it listed a bunch of things in the `NAME:, TITLE:` format.

Comment: Yes, I dont have a local env now, but when I did, the auth flow is similar, there was a url generated during the auth from local terminal and you could do the authN login from browser then.

Comment: Oh I need to login from the terminal? What is the command?

Comment: Yes, you do, see here https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login and dont forget to do project set.

Comment: A simple `gcloud auth login` fixed it but... I noticed that when I do `gcloud config list`, the `account` is no longer my service account but rather my overall Google Account. I re-activated my service account with gcloud auth activate-service-account <SERVICE ACCOUNT NAME>@<MY PROJECT NAME>.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file
=... And now I still get the same `ERROR: (gcloud.services.list) User ... does not have permission to access projects instance ...`

Comment: Sorry, you are doing service-list for service account, that looks like your existing IAM permission is not granted to do so. The service account requires oauth scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only
to do this action: ref docs: https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/services/list

Comment: I don't think either link shows how to set an oauth scope for a service account. How do I actually set my service account to have `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only` scope?

Comment: Yes, the easier way is as you answered yourself, find the role with this scope and add the role :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem seemed to stem from the fact that I needed to set the service account to have the role of `serviceusage.serviceUsageViewer`. In order to do that I need to run the `add-iam-policy-binding` command but this command needs to be run with an account that has account owner/editor permissions.

Step 1 was to switch the account in gcloud to the master gmail account with which I signed up for GCP services.

I set my gcloud "account" to my master Gmail account with `gcloud config set account <MASTER GMAIL ACCOUNT>`. Then I ran:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <PROJECT ID> \
    --member "serviceAccount:<SERVICE ACCOUNT>@<PROJECT ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --role "roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageViewer"
```

That command succeeded. I set the gcloud account back to the service account with `gcloud config set account <SERVICE ACCOUNT EMAIL>` and then ran `gcloud services list --available`. This command worked this time.